# IOS Memory Management - writing video to temp file

Tags: ios, memory-management, avplayer, writetofile

I'm creating an app that plays back multiple videos and photos in a snapchat story fashion. I fetch each of these videos data and write it to a temp file in order to play with `AVPlayer`.

```
NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), [NSString stringWithFormat:@"output%i.mov", i]];
[data writeToFile:outputPath atomically:YES];
```

---

In `viewWillDissapear` I delete all of these files with:

```
NSArray* tmpDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() error:NULL];
for (NSString *file in tmpDirectory) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), file] error:NULL];
}
```

But when I look at how much memory my app is using, in settings, its around 300 mb. Is there a way to see what is actually taking up all this memory? I would think this is high since I'm not caching anything besides the currentUser data (name, profileImage). 
Should I be doing something else to clean the temp files?

Comment: "Is there a way to see what is actually taking up all this memory" Instruments.

Answer (score 1):

But this line is absolutely wrong:

```
[data writeToFile:outputPath atomically:YES];
```

The implication is that at some moment — this moment — you are holding an entire video in memory (as `data`). That is completely incorrect; it should never happen. You should download to a file on disk, and if necessary, write that file to another file; you should never attempt to load the entire video into memory at once.

Comment: How am I suppose to play the video with `AVPlayer` if i do not load the data and then create an `NSURL`?  "download to a file on disk" , - just read this on dev "in iOS, because downloading directly to the file system is discouraged" , are your referring to using `NSURLSession`   @matt

Comment: "How am I suppose to play the video with AVPlayer if i do not load the data and then create an NSURL" You have an NSURL, that is exactly why you would _not_ need to load the data! You give a file URL or a remote URL. You _never_ "load the data" yourself. The AVPlayer does not need all the data to be in memory at once at any time; that is the wonderful thing about video playing.

Comment: Then download to a file and give the file URL as I have already said.

Comment: Can you provide some code of how to do this? Sorry this is my first time dealing with videos. I'm using parse to save vids as PFFiles. Are you saying just to set the player item to the pffile.url. If so, then yea like I said I've tried it and the videos were very laggy

Comment: How to do what? The question was about your memory management. I believe I've answered that. Do not fetch the video data into memory at all, ever.

Answer (score 1):

As @peter mentioned, you can use streaming [Video streaming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html).

Or else If you really want to download video file and store it into the disk space and want to utilize it later part then you should follow apple recommended way i.e NSFileHandle class to optimize your application heap memory while downloading larger files.

[NSFileHandle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/seekToEndOfFile)